# Installing/Setting cakePHP on Server

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to setup my cakephp work on server
Purchased godaddy shared server

when i go to my site http://xyz.com/cake/
I'm getting 404 error

```
The requested URL /xyz/cake/app/webroot/ was not found on this server.
```

anyhelp plz ??

Thanks,
Satish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the correct `RewriteBase` in your `.htaccess` if you're going to run Cake inside a subdirectory.

Both `/xyz/cake/.htaccess` and `/xyz/cake/webroot/.htaccess` (assuming `/xyz/cake` is the path  to Cake and your app dir) need to be updated.

/xyz/cake/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /xyz/cake/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

/xyz/cake/webroot/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /xyz/cake/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```